# Orignal Krawczyk's HKDF vs latest NIST SP800-56C

Tags: hmac, hkdf

I've noticed that the original HKDF in [rfc5869](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5869) defines a feedback loop. So the pseudo-code is something like:

```
for i = 1...n
    out[i] = HMAC(key, out[i - 1] + i + info)
```

However, the NIST recommendation [800-56C](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-56Cr1.pdf) seems to only depend on a loop counter for each round:

```
for i = 1...n
    out[i] = HMAC(key, i + info)
```

From a security perspective, is there any significant weakness if we don't do the feedback loop?

Comment: The second NIST document doesn’t seem to contain the string `HMAC` at all. I don’t think it is meant as a specification of HMAC but as a definition of an NIST-approved KDF that works with several hash/MAC functions but is not in fact HMAC.

Comment: Yes, the second document is more generic and works with various hash/MAC. I'm just wondering if there are any significant weakness assuming i choose the same hash/HMAC?